# How to add after success callback

Tags: jquery

Basically I need to clear this form, clearform:true has no impact, if I empty the text box in the submitHandler, the values aren't sent.

```
$("#bottomContent").on('click', "#Button6", function(){
$("#Form6").validate({
    errorContainer: "#Msg6",
    errorLabelContainer: "#Msg6 ul",
    errorElement: "li",
    resetForm: true,
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        $('#prcs6').fadeIn('fast').delay(2000).fadeOut('fast');
        $('#StartDate, #EndDate').delay(2000);
        form.submit();
        return false;

    },
    rules: {
        StartDate: {
            required: {
                depends: function(element) {
                    return !$('#AllDates').is(':checked');
                }
            }
        },
        EndDate: {
            required: {
                depends: function(element) {
                    return $('#StartDate').val()!="";
                }
            }
        }
    },
    messages: {
        StartDate: {
            required: "Please enter a starting date"
        },
        EndDate: {
            required: "Please enter an ending date"
        }
    }
});
});
```

I can't get the supplied success method to do anything either. Is there an easy way to emtpy the inputs after submit?

Answer (score 0):

turns out this was happening in Chrome, clearing the form fields before submit still held values in FF. this was my work around

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
    $('#prcs6').fadeIn('fast').delay(2000).fadeOut('fast');
    form.submit();
    setTimeout(function(){ // Delay for Chrome
            $('#StartDate, #EndDate').val(''); // blank the input
    }, 500);
    return false;
},
```